# How do you update an attachment in the Media Library using Sitecore's Web API?

Tags: media-library, item-web-api

I am currently using Sitecore's RESTful ItemService API and CURL to create assets in the Media Library and have that working just fine.

However, in some cases, I need to update the attachment (i.e. file) associated with the media item, rather than creating a new media item. The current documentation I am referencing is the one for Sitecore 6.6 (found [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf)), but the documentation does not cover how to update the attachment associated with a media item.

Is this even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't find a solution you may check out the SPE Remoting module.

Comment: bushland25     if you consider media file as a blob field, can you use the item api to update the media item? check this http://www.sitecorecoding.com/2016/08/update-item-name-using-sitecore-item.html

Comment: Hi @phani, I'll take a look at that. We're storing files on the file system (vs. database) but I'll take a look. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Thanks @michael-west as well for your suggestion, I'll look into it.